# Limit the number of times each option in a dropdown can be selected

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with 16 rows.

Each cell in column A has a dropdown list with 10 items.

I want to set a limit for each of these items so that, for example, the first one couldn’t be selected more than 3 times, the second one no more than 2 times and so on.

Is it feasible with or without VBA?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this in the sheet module:

```
Option Explicit

Private OldValue As Variant


Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Storing the old value of the newly selected cell
    OldValue = Target.Value2
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Check if the cell that was changed is in column A
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Me.Range("A1:A1000"), Target.Value2) > 2 Then
        
            MsgBox "You can't select more than 2 times the value: " & Target.Value2
            'Reset to the old value
            Target.Value2 = OldValue
        End If

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    'If the worksheet just got activated, make sure we have the value of the active cell stored.
    If IsEmpty(OldValue) Then
        OldValue = ActiveCell.Value2
    End If
End Sub
```

Basically, you have to use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event to store the previous value of the cell when it is selected. Then after the user tries to make a change to the cell, the `Worksheet_Change` event will look through the first 1000 cells of column A (you can always customize this amount) with the `COUNTIF` function.

Then, if the number of occurrences of the newly selected value is too high (>2 in this case), an error message is displayed and the value is set back to the previous value.

For safety measures, I've added the `Worksheet_Activate` event code to make sure that we have the value of the cell even if the user arrives from another sheet and doesn't change the selected cell.

If you want to have different limits for the number of repetitions allowed, you could add a `Select Case` that would handle that :

```
    ...
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim UpperLimit As Long
        
        Select Case Target.Value2
            Case Is = "First value": UpperLimit = 3
            Case Is = "Second value": UpperLimit = 2
            Case Is = "Third value": UpperLimit = 1
            Case Else: UpperLimit = 2  'Default limit
        End Select
        
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Me.Range("A1:A1000"), Target.Value2) > UpperLimit Then
            MsgBox "You can't select more than "UpperLimit & " times the value " & Target.Value2
            
            Target.Value2 = OldValue
        End If
    ...
```

Additionally, you might want to prevent people to copy paste in that region. If that's the case, this could be useful to you:
https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/CatchPaste.asp